# In YII2 and mongodb, how to write a rule for username not exist while updating the user?

Tags: mongodb, yii2, exists

```
['username', 'unique', 'targetClass'=>'\common\models\User', 
            'filter'=>function($query){

    if(!$this->getModel()->isNewRecord){

        $query->andWhere(['NOT', ['_id'=>$this->getModel()->id]]);
    }
    }
],
```

I am using the above code and showing error:

> "Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException Found unknown
>   operator in query: NOT "

Answer (score 1):

In Yii2 not use operator `not`. All operators see that - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md#operator-format-

In your code change:

```
   $query->andWhere(['not in', '_id', [$this->getModel()->id]]);
```

Comment: After change it showing the error "Condition should be an array"

Comment: still showing the same error "Condition should be an array"

Comment: You use `$query->where`? Not use '$query->andWhere'?

Comment: Yes i am using where instead of andWhere.

Comment: Hm... ok. Try use that: `$query->andWhere(['not in', '_id', [$this->getModel()->id]]);`

Comment: Yes it is working - $query->andWhere(['not in', '_id', [$this->getModel()->id]]);